# Как поменять текст в виджете "Корзина" woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Как поменять текст на странице "Корзина" woocommerce. Мне нужно поменять английский текст на картинке и убрать кнопку "Update cart"
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Товарищи закрыатели вопросов!!!  Если  вам не понятна суть вопроса -  вы не знаете ВП. Проходите пож мимо этой метки! Достали, уже своей некомпитентостью!  Вопрос более чем понятный.

Answer (score 0):

woocommerce переведён на русский [полностью](https://translate.wordpress.org/projects/wp-plugins/woocommerce).

А за внешний вид отвечает тема.
Таким образом если что-то на фронте не по русски - "виновата" тема.  Или же какие-то доп плагины.
Т.е. нужно переводить тему или др плагины.